# Declaring a Linked List Node

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Please bear with me if its too BASIC or silly, but I want to know , when we have a node structure as :-

```
struct node {
 int data ;            //data
 struct node* next;    //pointer
}
```

Why do we declare a node as :-

```
struct node* new_node = null;
```

or

```
struct node* new_node= (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

and why not just `struct node new_node = null`
?

Comment: So you know the difference between variables that life on the stack and one that life on the heap?

Comment: @ckruczek okay,  i looked it up , so one has to use pointers to access memory on heap . thanks.

Comment: in C, capitalization counts!   'null' means nothing to the compiler.  use 'NULL'.   in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() as it is a void* and can be assigned to any pointer.   When calling malloc() always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a node that way, but you need to initialize it properly then.

struct node new_node = {5 , NULL};
will create a node called new_node with data set to 5 and next set to NULL.

The question is more or less what you actually need. When you create a node like this within a function, the node will cease to exist once the function is finished, if you don't make a copy of it. This is often not desirable.

But if you need to make a copy anyway of such a node, you can just get the memory for the "copy" in the first place with malloc and fill the data right in the "copy" just via a pointer to the node, instead of putting the node on the function stack.

Answer (score 1):

In the first two you declare pointers to a struct or node:

`struct node* new_node;` is a pointer, or the adress of a struct

And in your suggestion you declare a whole struct or node:

`struct node new_node;` this is a struct that will live in the stack.

and you can not assign null to a struct, at least in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Because `node` is the name of the `struct` and `new_node` is the name of the variable.  The `*` means that `new_node` is only the address of the `struct`, hence you need to allocate memory to it using `malloc`.

You could define your own custom types for the struct:

```
typedef struct node_struct_tag       //tag, for use within the struct
{
    int data ;                       //data
    struct node_struct_tag* next;    //pointer
}   node, *node_pointer;             //types
```

Now you can declare the new node using the simplified syntax that you suggest.

```
node_pointer newNode = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a more readable struct like this

```
typedef int Type;
typedef struct node * Ptr;

typedef struct node {
    Type Element;
    Ptr  Next;
} Node;
```

A new node can be cleanly defined as

```
Ptr newNode = NULL;
```

or

```
Ptr newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```